# Mockito object always giving a NullPointer exception

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockito

This is the class that I want to test.

```kotlin
open class Foo(bar :Bar){
   fun someMethod() = bar.anotherMethod()
}
```

And I have a builder class to get `Foo` mock instance since Mockito cant mock constructor arguments.

```kotlin
open class FooBuilder{
   fun makeFoo(bar:Bar) = Foo(bar)
}
```

Here is my approach to make the mock Objects and verify.

```kotlin
var fooBuilderMock = mock(FooBuilder::class)
var barMock = mock(Bar::class)
var fooMock = mock(Foo::class) 
Mockito.`when`(fooBuilderMock.makeFoo(barMock)).thenReturn(fooMock)
fooMock.someMethod()
Mockito.verify(barMock, Mockito.times(1)).anotherMethod()
```

I am getting a null pointer exception on `barMock` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the Builder, there is no need for it. Additionally, don't mock the class that you are trying to test. If you do it, your test makes no sense.

```kotlin
class FooTest {

    private val barMock = mock(Bar::class)
    private lateinit var foo: Foo

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        foo = Foo(barMock)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Your test name`() {
        // Arrange
        Mockito.`when`(barMock.anotherMethod()).thenReturn(// whatever it should return)

        // Act
        fooMock.someMethod()

        // Assert
        Mockito.verify(barMock, Mockito.times(1)).anotherMethod()
    }
}
```

As a side note consider taking a look at [mockk](https://mockk.io/) and using it instead of Mockito. It is implemented in kotlin and thus supports it since day 1. With it, your test would look similar but follow more the kotlin "style":

```kotlin
class FooTest {

    @MockK
    private lateinit var barMock = mock(Bar::class)
    private lateinit var foo: Foo

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        foo = Foo(barMock)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Your test name`() {
        // Arrange
        every { barMock.anotherMethod() } returns //whatever it should return

        // Act
        foo.someMethod()

        // Assert
        verify(exactly = 1) { barMock.anotherMethod() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! Seems mockk library also very useful